# How do I add mapview at the end of table as a footer (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, mapkit

I am working with Xcode (Swift) I have tableview with custom cells. I want to add mapview at the end of the table as a footer.  Table cells show addresses and then at the end the footer will show dots on the map.  Any idea how to:
1) add footer, 
2) insert map into that footer, 
3) add dots (addresses with geo lacation) to the map.

Any direction on where should I start or example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone needs

1.&2.)

```
var mapView = MKMapView()
```

in ViewDidLoad()

.......

```
mapView.mapType = .Standard
mapView.frame = view.frame
table.tableFooterView = mapView
```

3.) Use annotations